# form submission doesn't bring up error message if empty

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to have an error message displayed if I try to submit an empty form. the below code shows what SHOULD be happening.

```
 function prepareEventHandlers() {
document.getElementById("frmContact").onsubmit = function () {
    if (document.getElementById("email").value == '') {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = 'Please provide at least an email address!';
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = '';
        return true;
    }
};
}


window.onload = function () {
prepareEventHandlers();
}
```

Here is the code for my cshtml side of it:

```
<form id="frmContact" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Personal Information</legend>
<p>email and other elements here.</p>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" checked="false" />
Remind me later <br />
</div>
<p><span id="errorMessage"></span></p>
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="send"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
<script src="http://localhost:53734/Scripts/JScript3.js"></script>
```

I tried debugging it, but it doesn't call the prepareEventHandlers method on click. also, tried sticking the script tag above the form, but this didn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has no input element for the email. Your JavaScript is looking for an element with the ID of email (presumably an input) with `document.getElementById("email").value` but your form is missing it.

Change:

```
<p>email and other elements here.</p>
```

to:

```
<p><input id="email" /></p>
```

And then your code works fine. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KKCnF/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have to have an element with a corresponding ID for the validation to work . . .Here you don't have an email id element but you are trying to validate

try the following

```
<input type="text" id="email"/>
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ED2BF/)